# can't get my code in github with capistrano

Tags: git, github, capistrano

I did branch to HEAD switching (and can't remember the things I did) on my github repository and now I can't seem to make capistrano work.

when I...

```
set :branch, "master"
```

it says master is not repository

```
set :branch, "origin"
```

it does succeed, however, it's not getting my code at all, it only shows the REVISION file.

```
# set branch removed
```

it says "HEAD" is not a repository.

so far the following are the contents of my deploy.rb

```
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_to, "redport"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

set :use_sudo, false
set :user, 'netxph'
set :repostiory, "https://netxph@github.com/netxph/redport.git"
set :repository_cache, "git-cache"
set :scm_verbose, true
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it...

I misspelled the repository (refer above) and have another duplicate of repository with empty values in it.

:(